# Why lldb change Swift's temp var does not work?

Tags: swift, lldb

There is a temp var `tmp` as a `NSObject` instance,
I added a breakpoint, which does `express tmp = nil` before print action, and I can see this `tmp` really became `nil` in the vars list.

However, it still printed the old `NSObject` instance, why?

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Comment: It may be optimized (notice the "never mutated" warning), or the next instruction has been prepared by the time you execute the breakpoint. Is there a real-world example where this is affecting you?

Comment: For example, I want to test some code in ObjC, then I wrote something like "BOOL test = NO; if (test) { // dosomething }", and make a breakpoint to change the test's value into YES, it will excute the test code.

Answer (score 3):

For technical reasons having to do with how swift resolves the conflict between being a "safe" language, which requires a lot of bookkeeping, and being "swift" which requires optimization of the bookkeeping work even at `-Onone`, the compiler can only present an "always available" local variable to lldb by making a (from its perspective) read-only copy of the variable, and pointing the debugger at that.  So in many cases, the debugger doesn't know where the in-use version of the variable lives, and changes to the debugger copy don't affect the program execution.

That is what you are seeing here.